# Press delete (backspace) in EditText with espresso

Tags: android, android-testing, android-espresso

I writing a test case in espresso that requires performing a delete (backspace). The code I came up is like this

```
onView(withId(R.id.testNumberEditText))
            .perform(replaceText("123"))
            .perform(pressKey(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL))
            .check { view, _ ->
                assertEquals("12", (view as EditText).text.toString())
            }
```

But this code doesn't work and the text is still `123`. Any idea what I'm doing wrong on what key should I press to get the desired outcome?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change your code to this :

```
onView(withId(R.id.etTesting))
                .perform(replaceText("123"))
                .perform(click())
                .perform(pressKey(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL))
                .check(matches(withText("12")));
```

Comment: do you know what click() does here? Can you explain about his?

Comment: Yes, I did not find the way to set focus to the last char, so I perform a click to put the focus to the last char and then I delete, something that a normal person would do :P

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `replaceText`, use `typeText`, which will leave the cursor at the end.

```
onView(withId(R.id.testNumberEditText))
        .perform(typeText("123"))
        .perform(pressKey(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL))
        .check { view, _ ->
            assertEquals("12", (view as EditText).text.toString())
        }
```